# Fill in PDF form using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a fillable PDF and would like to use PHP to populate the fields and output the file as a flat PDF. Is there any PHP code available for doing that on a hosted web server without direct command line access? Although I am familiar with PHP, I am uncertain on how to proceed with using PHP to fill in the PDF

To be clear... I am not seeking a PDF creation solution, I am trying to figure out how to populate fields in an existing PDF

Comment: No.... PDFTK requires an install which is not available in a hosted environment

Comment: The second and third answers work without installing anything externally though.